# Resize my btrfs filesystem to add the free unallocated space

Tags: disk-partitioning

I fail to add the unallocated space to "/dev/nvme0n1p6 btrs/,/home"
i can't move or resize either of /dev/nvme0n1p5 or /dev/nvme0n1p6
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways you could resize your partition or filesystem.

### Resizing a partition using `gparted`

This seems what you are trying to achieve by sharing the gparted screenshot.
In `parted` man page it says that resizing is about:

```
Change the end position of  partition
```

Which means you need to have room after a partition to extend it. Which is not your case here. Hence the impossibility  to resize.

What you will have to do is to delete your partitions 5 and 6 (if you have no data on them and you know what you're doing) and recreate new bigger partitions using and starting from the currently unallocated space.

### Alternative: resizing the btrfs filesystem

I assume you're on Linux and have btrfs-progs (btrfs utilities) installed.
There is a way where you can just extend your btrfs filesystem which is mounted as your `/home` apparently, and extend it of the size of the unallocated space.

For this is do the following:

- create a partition from the unallocated space let's call it `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, you don't have to format it to anything yet.
- continue with /home already mounted (in case it wasn't)
- then extend the btrfs filesystem of your home as follows:

```
  btrfs device add /dev/nvme0n1p4 /home
```

- then you can just check with `df -hT` that your /home mounted partition would have doubled in size.

You can also check the organization of the btrfs filesystem for your /home by calling:
`btrfs filesystem usage /home`

Good dreams!

Comment: I'm using a VirtualBox machine. My `/home` directory was mounted and couldn't be resized, expanding the filesystem through the VirtualBox interface and then following the steps above helped a lot! Thanks!